# AngularJS checkbox ng-change issue with $event.target

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I'm writing a simple AngularJS Controller that keeps track of the number of checkboxes checked.  Trying to avoid `$scope.$watch` and instead use `ng-change` to increment/decrement the total count.

**HTML**:

```
<form ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
      <td>
      <input type="checkbox" 
             value="{{item.id}}"
             ng-model="item.selected"
             ng-change="updateTotal($event)"> &nbsp; {{item.name}}
       </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>
      Total checked: {{totalSelected}}
   </p>
</form>
```

**Controller snippet**

```
$scope.updateTotal = function($event) {

    var checkbox = $event.target;

    if (checkbox.checked) {
      $scope.totalSelected++;
    }
    else {
      $scope.totalSelected--;
    } 
}
```

I keep getting an error in the controller where I attempt to access `$event.target`:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
```

**I created a Plunk for recreating: http://plnkr.co/edit/qPzETejmMHHZCQ2sV2Sk?p=info**

If anyone has any ideas or suggestions I would be very grateful.

Thank you very much!

Comment: @levi is correct. But more philosophically, avoid `checkbox.checked` (or anything so DOM-related) in the controller. Instead send the `item` (or `item.selected`).

Comment: @DRobinson That makes sense, thanks.  You're right with your suggestion to not couple it so tightly to the DOM.

Comment: @levi, if we have to stop event propagation inside `ng-change`, how can we achieve that?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`ng-change` function doesn't allow to pass `$event` as variable.

From an collaborator in AngularJS official github repo:

> ng-change is not a directive for handling the change event (I realize
>   that this is confusing given the name), but is actually instead
>   notified when ngModelController.$setViewValue() is called and the
>   value changes (because ng-change adds a listener to the
>   $viewChangeListeners collection). So this is as expected.

You can read more about it [ng-change doesn't get the $event argument](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6370)

**How can you solve your requirement?**

Just pass `item.selected` to your ng-change function and check its value.

HTML

```
  <input type="checkbox" 
         value="{{item.id}}"
         ng-model="item.selected"
         ng-change="updateTotal(item.selected)"> &nbsp; {{item.name}}
```

Controller

```
$scope.updateTotal = function(item_selected) {

    if (item_selected) {
      $scope.totalSelected++;
    }
    else {
      $scope.totalSelected--;
    } 
}
```

**UPDATED**

You can test it here, in this [**plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ms5BnVxzVqOuR8ypGWae?p=preview)

Comment: That looks very elegant solution and it meets DRobinson's suggestion of not using checkbox.checked.  Will try it when I get home, thanks!

Comment: @PhilipTenn I prepared a plnkr for you, check my answer.

Comment: what if we want to detach it with the model value?