# Why is $event not working with ng-change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my html tag which has ng-change event and I am passing $event as an arg to it.

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="dynamicField.value" ng-change="myFunction(dynamicField,$event)"/>
```

Below is my angularJS function-

```
$scope.myFunction=function(dynamicField,event){
alert(event);
}
```

whenever this function is called, the alert shows event's value as 'undefined'.

Please guide me.

Comment: What you have to do with $event?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108858/angularjs-checkbox-ng-change-issue-with-event-target

Comment: Pass $event first and then your custom parameters.

Comment: pass  `dynamicField.value` function insted of  `dynamicField`

Answer (score 2):

From `angular.js`, `ngChange` directive registers an

> Angular expression to be executed when input changes due to user
>   interaction with the input element.

The directive just adds the evaluated expression to the list of view change listeners,

```
var ngChangeDirective = valueFn({
  restrict: 'A',
  require: 'ngModel',
  link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
    ctrl.$viewChangeListeners.push(function() {
      scope.$eval(attr.ngChange);
    });
  }
});
```

Once `$modelValue` is update, these listeners get executed one at a time,

```
this.$$writeModelToScope = function() {
    ngModelSet($scope, ctrl.$modelValue);
    forEach(ctrl.$viewChangeListeners, function(listener) {
      try {
        listener();
      } catch (e) {
        $exceptionHandler(e);
      }
    });
  };
```

As you see no events get passed around, because all `ngChange` does is executes the expression upon an update of the `ngModel`. It's a good way to make sure that your expression runs after the model value gets set.

As opposed to `ngChange` `ngClick` passes the `$event` into the click handling function, because it handles a DOM event,

```
forEach(
  'click dblclick mousedown mouseup mouseover mouseout mousemove mouseenter mouseleave keydown keyup keypress submit focus blur copy cut paste'.split(' '),
  function(eventName) {
    var directiveName = directiveNormalize('ng-' + eventName);
    ngEventDirectives[directiveName] = ['$parse', '$rootScope', function($parse, $rootScope) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function($element, attr) {
          // We expose the powerful $event object on the scope that provides access to the Window,
          // etc. that isn't protected by the fast paths in $parse.  We explicitly request better
          // checks at the cost of speed since event handler expressions are not executed as
          // frequently as regular change detection.
          var fn = $parse(attr[directiveName], /* interceptorFn */ null, /* expensiveChecks */ true);
          return function ngEventHandler(scope, element) {
            element.on(eventName, function(event) {
              var callback = function() {
                fn(scope, {$event:event});
              };
              if (forceAsyncEvents[eventName] && $rootScope.$$phase) {
                scope.$evalAsync(callback);
              } else {
                scope.$apply(callback);
              }
            });
          };
        }
      };
    }];
  }
);
```

You see on occurrence of the event, the DOM event object gets passed into the handling function as `$event`, `fn(scope, {$event:event});`.