# How to capture the event of ng-change?

Tags: angularjs, dom-events

Here's my code, But the `$event` is undefined. Does anyone know how can I capture the event?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.alert = function ($event){
            alert($event);
        }
    });
</script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div ng-init="names=['A', 'B', 'C']">
    <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="fda" ng-change="alert($event)" ng-options="value for value in names">
    </select>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ng-change` is not a directive for *handling* the change event (I realize that this is confusing given the name). So this is as expected. [Github source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6370)

If you need to get the event, you can use ng-click instead:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.alert = function ($event){
            alert($event);
        }
    });
</script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div ng-init="names=['A', 'B', 'C']">
    <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="fda" ng-click="alert($event)" ng-options="value for value in names">
    </select>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 9):

**ngMouse, ng-change does not provide an event object**.

But my suggestion is to create another variable, assign `$event` to that, then pass it via `ng-change`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.alert = function ($event){
            alert($event);
        }
    });
</script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div ng-init="names=['A', 'B', 'C']">
    <select 
        class="form-control input-sm" 
        ng-click="event = $event" 
        ng-model="fda" 
        ng-change="alert(event)" 
        ng-options="value for value in names">
    </select>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

[More details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108858/angularjs-checkbox-ng-change-issue-with-event-target)

Answer (score 1):

**Capture event beforehand**

If you need the ng-change functionality but also want to get the element being changed you could also use ng-focus to capture the element before change.

```
<select ... ng-focus="setFocus($event)" ng-change="alert()" ... />
```

Expanded example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

   var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
   app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

       $scope.alert = function($event) {
           if ($scope.currentElement) {
               alert($scope.currentElement.value);
           }
       }

       $scope.setFocus = function(event) {
           $scope.currentElement = event.target;
       }
       $scope.cancelFocus = function(event) {
           $scope.currentElement = false;
       }
   });
  
  </script>
 </head>

 <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
     <div ng-init="names=['A', 'B', 'C']">
         <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="fda" ng-change="alert()" ng-focus="setFocus($event)" ng-blur="cancelFocus($event)" ng-options="value for value in names">
         </select>
     </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.alert = function ($event){
            let elmSelect = angular.element(e.target)[0];
            let options = elmSelect.options;
            let selectedOptionInnerHmtl = options[options.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
            // and so on ...
        }
    });
</script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div ng-init="names=['A', 'B', 'C']">
    <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="fda" ng-click="e=$event"ng-change="alert(e)" ng-options="value for value in names">
    </select>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't, [this answer](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6370) is taken from a quick google search result:

```
ng-change is not a directive for handling the change event
(I realize that this is confusing given the name), but is actually
instead notified when ngModelController.$setViewValue() is called
and the value changes (because ng-change adds a listener to the 
$viewChangeListeners collection). So this is as expected.
```